# Correct mistakes

Tags: grammar

I've been given specific task and I want to consult with you.So there is a phone conversation about going to the mall.I need to correct 9 mistakes in the use of modals,modal-like expressions,be verbs and auxiliaries.

Here is how I've done it.

[image]

What do you think about it.Did I make everything right?

And I still wonder how can Kelly say "**while you're here**"if she is not here yet.Maybe she could have said **when you'll be here**???I dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"While you're here" I would leave in as correct.

However, "You're not against free food, aren't you?" is an unusual tag: normally you invert the tag, so I would correct that to:

> You're not against free food, *are you*?

And indeed, you *might* have seen it in the news sounds better than *could*, as Crazy Eyes mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one, even though I looked through. Double negatives are a no-no.

Answer (score 1):

"While you're here" does not imply that Tina is "here" yet. I'm not sure where you got that idea. Kelly is simply suggesting that Tina go with her to the mall when she gets there. "While" can mean "when the following occurs" or "during this occurrence" (which may or may not have happened yet). "Let's go get a haircut. While we're there, we can also get our nails done." The speaker hasn't arrived at the salon yet; she is describing events in the future.

"You could have seen it in the news" is technically correct, but a gross idiomatic error. Most likely, your teacher was looking for "You **might** have seen it in the news."

Comment: If **"while you're here"** is normal,then where is ninth mistake?